# Name this property: product of functions = function of sum

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions, terminology

Consider a function $f(x)$ with the property $f(a)f(b) = f(a+b)$, where $a,b$ are numbers  (or matrices, or operators). Is there a name for this property?

For example, $f(x)=c^x$ for a fixed $c \in \mathbb{R}$ will do this.

This comes up often enough in my physics research that I would really like to refer to it by either an existing name or give it a reasonable one.

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous function $R \to R$, then the only solutions for $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)$ are $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=c^x, c>0$. There is probably no need for special name.

Comment: Exponential function is what I would call it, if it can be assumed to be piecewise continuous.

Comment: A [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism)?

Comment: In my case the arguments are operators that do not abide by normal matrix-style addition and multiplication (annoyingly unintuitive), so I was hoping for an evocative name, perhaps based on abstract algebra. "Ring Homomorphism" is close, but strictly either $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ or $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$, not mixed.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation):

> This equation is sometimes referred to as Cauchy's additive functional equation to distinguish it from Cauchy's exponential functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$.